# Testing redirect links to external sites

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have a link on a page `/my/example/page` which links to a laravel route `my.route`.

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Some\Custom\Auth\Middleware:1']], function () {
        Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/my/route/to/external/controller', 'exampleController@externalLink')->name('my.route');
    }
}
```

Link on `/my/example/page`

```
<a href="/my/route/to/external/controller">Link</a>
```

This route `/my/route/to/external/controller` points to this controller method `externalLink` in the `exampleController` controller, which returns the url for the href to use

```
public function externalLink()
{
    return $this->redirect->away('www.externalsite.com');
}
```

My test is

```
$this->visit(/my/example/page)
     ->click('Link')
     ->assertRedirectedToRoute('my.route');
```

I constantly get the error

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

when I use the `click()` testing method.

I can catch this using `@expectedException` but his doesn't help as I am expecting to see a different page.

I have also tried (not together);

```
->assertResponseStatus(200);
->seePageIs('www.externalsite.com');
->assertRedirect();
->followRedirects();
```

From browser inspection, when the url is clicked I get

```
http://www.example.com/my/route/to/external      302
http://www.externalsite.com                      200
```

How can I functionally test the button **being clicked** and redirecting to an external site?

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: @tptcat I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am struggling with a similar problem right now, and I have just about given up on testing the endpoint directly. Opting for a solution like this...

Test that the link contains proper information in the view:

```
$this->visit('/my/example/page')
    ->seeElement('a', ['href' => route('my.route')]);
```

Moving the logic in the controller to something you can test directly. The [Laravel\Socialite package](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/tests/OAuthTwoTest.php) has some interesting tests that might be helpful if you do this...

```
class ExternalLinkRedirect {
    public function __construct($request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function redirect()
    {
        return redirect()->away('exteranlsite.com');
    }
}
```

Then test it directly

```
    $route = route('my.route');
    $request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create($route);
    $redirector = new ExternalLinkRedirect($request);
    $response = $redirector->redirect();
    $this->assertEquals('www.externalsite.com', $response->getTargetUrl());
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use the `get` method instead of `visit`.

An example:

`$this->get('/facebook')
     ->assertRedirectedTo('https://www.facebook.com/Les-Teachers-du-NET-516952535045054');`

Comment: There's no `assertRedirectedTo` method.