# Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse"

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

Controller code:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.patient.edit', $patientId);
```

Test code:

```
$this->visit(route('admin.patient.edit', $this->patient->id))
     ->press('Update');

$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('admin.patient.edit', [$this->patient->id]);
```

The error I get is this:

```
Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class 
"Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse".
```

I've printed out the response from the inside the test and inside the controller and it is in fact a **RedirectReponse** Object. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that your overall code in the controller works as expected and no errors occur, like csrf token mismatch excpetion. You can show the reponse content to investigate more.

Answer (score 2):

As mercuryseries stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341866/3005056, the visit method might not be what you are looking for since it follows redirection.

"A simple way is to use the get method instead of visit.

An example:

```
$this->get('/facebook')
     ->assertRedirectedTo('https://www.facebook.com/Les-Teachers-du-NET-516952535045054');"
```